# Is there a way to isolate the edge of a 2D Wireframe with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I have a 2D wireframe (no faces) on the left and I would like to achieve the result on the right with geometry nodes. Any ideas on how to do this?[image]
I lost a couple of hours to try to solve this puzzle with no success.

Comment: It's actually a hard problem to solve I think. You can start exploring the convex hull node.

Comment: Sure, that seems to be one of the ways to go. but how would you do it if you did know from which edge you'd start? I know how to get the shortest path but not how to get the longest one. *This was reffering to the comment you deleted*

Comment: Convex hull doesn't seem to help at all since some of the edge vertices disappear inside it

Comment: Yeah I deleted the comment because I realized it was wrong. :) Convex hull doesn't cut it I know, but it's a step forward. You can also explore this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnSg5iOS4QU with the new, experimental simulation nodes

Comment: I thougt about turning this wireframe into mesh of faces, but still have no idea how to achive it. I would know how to fill multiple closed mesh loops but I dont know how to separate these rectangles that create this wireframe mesh  from one another. Any suggestions in this direction?

Comment: I litteraly hate simulation nodes, once they make true loop nodes I'll be the first to use them, but these simulation nodes seem like a lot of work for developers for only a fraction of the benefit.

Comment: Well,I have exhausted my GN knowledge. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

If your mesh also has faces, you can solve this by checking the number of faces connected to the edges, and feeding only this selection into the node `Delete Geometry`:

[image]

*...But since your mesh has no faces, this is not a solution for you (but maybe for others).*

Comment: Well, it doesn't have faces, that's the problem and that's why I specified that it's 2D wireframe and not mesh faces. I appreciate you trying to help, though, thanks

Comment: @VicMarco And that's why you're awarding a downvote? ...it would have been great if you explained that in your question...

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to downwote as an offense to you, Do you get some negative consequensces if your post gets downvoted? I'll remove the downvote if that's the case. I just thought it was not useful to the solution of the probelm.

Comment: @VicMarco If the answer itself is a solution (for a particular way), then a downvote is not adequate feedback. Then, in your place, I would simply not rate the answer at all. A downvote should be used when the answer is fundamentally wrong or misleading.

Comment: Ok, I'm very sorry, friend, I wasn't my intention to offend somene who was actually trying to help. Sorry again :)
I'll try to be more careful in the future and I'll change it as soon it lets me, it seems to be locked for a certain amount of time now. Anyway, other suggestions? ;)

Comment: @VicMarco, you can retract your downvote, I think. Thanks

Comment: @VicMarco To answer your question about negative consequences: Yes, getting a question or answer downvoted makes the one who posting the question or answer lose 2 reputation points. And you lose 1 point for downvoting an answer as well. So for us longtime users with a lot of reputation this might be not a big problem, but for new users with not so much reputation you should consider if a downvote is necessary/reasonable.